# How to shift rows up after deleting a row?

Tags: python, tkinter, jupyter-notebook

I have the code where you can tick a checkbox and delete any row you want but I can't figure out how to get the rows beneath the row deleted to shift up and fill the space from the deleted row. Here is the code I'm running in jupyter. Please help!!

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Editable Headings")

        self.headings = ['Pad #', 'Location Name', 'Projected Level',
                         '# 130 bbl Loads', '24hr Rate', 'Rate Per Tank',
                         '# of Tanks', 'Notes', 'Water weight']
        self.entries = []
        self.vars = []

        self.init_gui()

    def init_gui(self):
        for i, heading in enumerate(self.headings):
            label = tk.Label(self.root, text=heading, font=("TkDefaultFont", 14))
            label.grid(row=0, column=i, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

            entry = tk.Entry(self.root)
            entry.grid(row=1, column=i, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="we")
            self.entries.append(entry)

        var = tk.IntVar()
        checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(self.root, variable=var)
        checkbox.grid(row=1, column=len(self.headings), padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")
        self.vars.append(var)

        add_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="+", command=self.add_row)
        add_button.grid(row=1, column=len(self.headings)+1, padx=25, pady=10)

        delete_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Delete", command=self.delete_row)
        delete_button.grid(row=2, column=len(self.headings)+1, padx=25, pady=10)

    def add_row(self):
        row = len(self.entries) // len(self.headings) + 1
        for i, heading in enumerate(self.headings):
            entry = tk.Entry(self.root)
            entry.grid(row=row, column=i, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="we")
            self.entries.append(entry)

        var = tk.IntVar()
        checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(self.root, variable=var)
        checkbox.grid(row=row, column=len(self.headings), padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")
        self.vars.append(var)

    def delete_row(self):
        if not self.entries:
            return

        if messagebox.askyesno("Delete", "Are you sure you want to delete the selected rows?"):
            indices = [i for i, var in enumerate(self.vars) if var.get()]
            for i in sorted(indices, reverse=True):
                for j in range(len(self.headings)):
                    entry = self.entries.pop(i * len(self.headings))
                    entry.destroy()
                var = self.vars.pop(i)
                var.set(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = GUI(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I would just like the rows beneath the row that is selected to be deleted to shift up after the selected is deleted.

Comment: If you delete those checkbuttons that are checked as well, those entries will be shift up because rows without any widget will have zero height.

Answer (score 0):

For easier control, I would suggest to:

- put those entry boxes and checkbuttons in a frame and those action buttons in another frame
- use a single dictionary to store those widgets and `tk.IntVar` using *row number* as the key instead of separate lists

Then it is easy to delete the widgets in a row by just looking up them in the dictionary.  Note that if all widgets in a row are deleted, the height of that row will be zero.  So the widgets beneath will be shift up.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Editable Headings")

        self.headings = ['Pad #', 'Location Name', 'Projected Level',
                         '# 130 bbl Loads', '24hr Rate', 'Rate Per Tank',
                         '# of Tanks', 'Notes', 'Water weight']
        self.entries = {}

        self.init_gui()

    def init_gui(self):
        # frame for the entries and checkbuttons
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.frame.pack(side="left", fill="y")

        # show the headings
        for i, heading in enumerate(self.headings):
            label = tk.Label(self.frame, text=heading, font=("TkDefaultFont", 14))
            label.grid(row=0, column=i, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")
        # add an initial row
        self.add_row()

        # frame for the buttons
        button_frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
        button_frame.pack(side="right", fill="y")

        add_button = tk.Button(button_frame, text="+", command=self.add_row)
        add_button.grid(row=1, column=len(self.headings)+1, padx=25, pady=10)

        delete_button = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Delete", command=self.delete_row)
        delete_button.grid(row=2, column=len(self.headings)+1, padx=25, pady=10)


    def add_row(self):
        # get the insertion row number
        row = self.frame.grid_size()[1]

        widgets = []
        for i, heading in enumerate(self.headings):
            entry = tk.Entry(self.frame)
            entry.grid(row=row, column=i, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="we")
            widgets.append(entry)

        var = tk.IntVar()
        checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(self.frame, variable=var)
        checkbox.grid(row=row, column=len(self.headings), padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")
        widgets.append(checkbox)

        # store the widgets in the new row and IntVar into the dictionary
        self.entries[row] = (var, widgets)


    def delete_row(self):
        # any row selected
        rows = [row for row, (var, _) in self.entries.items() if var.get()]
        if rows and messagebox.askyesno("Delete", "Are you sure you want to delete the selected rows?"):
            for row in rows:
                _, widgets = self.entries.pop(row)
                for w in widgets:
                    w.destroy()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = GUI(root)
    root.mainloop()
```